# SQL join 2nd table based on time difference in first table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables, once holding the start time of an event, the second holding the end time of an event and I want to join the two

However the challenge is that there is not always a corresponding end event for every start event, and if so I want a NULL in the output. Is this possible?

Edit: Each ID represents an individual, which can have multiple events start and stop per day. For each event I only want the single 'correct' end time joined to the start time, if it exists. There is currently no individual-event level identifier.

For example:

**table 1:** start time

```
id      ts_start
123     01:00
123     03:00
123     05:00
123     09:00
```

**table 2:** end time

```
id      ts_end
123     02:00
123     07:00
```

**Output:**

```
id      ts_start    ts_end
123     01:00       02:00
123     03:00       NULL
123     05:00       07:00
123     09:00       NULL
```

I'm on MySQL 5.7 so don't have access to windowing/analytic functions yet, although if that's part of the best solution then I'm happy to migrate (has to be open source though, so a new version of MySQL or Postgres)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get a "candidate" for `ts_end`, which is the least end time greater than start time. That can be done either with

```
select s.id, s.ts_start, (
  select min(e.ts_end)
  from end_time e
  where e.id = s.id
    and e.ts_end > s.ts_start
) as ts_end
from start_time s;
```

or with

```
select s.id, s.ts_start, min(e.ts_end) as ts_end
from start_time s
left join end_time e
  on  e.id = s.id
  and e.ts_end > s.ts_start
group by s.id, s.ts_start
```

Both queries will return

```
|  id | ts_start |   ts_end |
|-----|----------|----------|
| 123 |    01:00 |    02:00 |
| 123 |    03:00 |    07:00 |
| 123 |    05:00 |    07:00 |
| 123 |    09:00 |     null |
```

Now we need `ts_end` to be `null` (second row) when there is any start time (table `start_time`) between `ts_start` and `ts_end`. For the second row `ts_end` must be `NULL`, because there is a start time `5:00` which is between `3:00` and `7:00`.

For the first query we could use a `HAVING` clause with a `NOT EXISTS` condition:

```
select s.id, s.ts_start, (
  select min(e.ts_end)
  from end_time e
  where e.id = s.id
    and e.ts_end > s.ts_start
  having not exists (
      select *
      from start_time s2
      where s2.id = s.id
        and s2.ts_start > s.ts_start
        and s2.ts_start < min(e.ts_end)
    )
) as ts_end
from start_time s
```

The second query can can be extended with a `CASE` expression and an `EXISTS` condition:

```
select s.id, s.ts_start, 
  case when exists (
      select *
      from start_time s2
      where s2.id = s.id
      and s2.ts_start > s.ts_start
      and s2.ts_start < min(e.ts_end)  
    ) 
    then null
    else min(e.ts_end)
  end as ts_end
from start_time s
left join end_time e
  on  e.id = s.id
  and e.ts_end > s.ts_start
group by s.id, s.ts_start
```

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `LEAD` window function instead:

```
select s.id, s.ts_start,
    case when min(e.ts_end) > lead(s.ts_start) over (partition by s.id order by s.ts_start)
        then null
        else min(e.ts_end)
    end as ts_end
from start_time s
left join end_time e
  on  e.id = s.id
  and e.ts_end > s.ts_start
group by s.id, s.ts_start
```

All three queries will return:

```
|  id | ts_start |   ts_end |
|-----|----------|----------|
| 123 |    01:00 |    02:00 |
| 123 |    03:00 |     null |
| 123 |    05:00 |    07:00 |
| 123 |    09:00 |     null |
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6qRaYZKnA7ZYMcTmpZFUwj/0

Answer (score 2):

You have to see if the next start is later than the next end.  One method uses a two correlated subqueries:

```
select id, ts_start,
       (case when next_start > next_end then next_end
        end) as ts_end
from (select s.*,
             (select max(s2.ts_start)
              from starts s2
              where s2.id = s.id and s2.ts_start > s.ts_start
             ) as next_start,
             (select min(e2.ts_end)
              from ends e2
              where e2.id = s.id and e2.ts_end > s.ts_end
             ) as next_end
      from starts s
     ) s;
```

With window functions, I would combine all the times together and look at the next value:

```
with t as (
      select id, ts_start as time, 'start' as which
      from starts
      union all
      select id, ts_end, 'end'
      from ends
     )
select t.id, t.time as ts_start,
       (case when next_which = 'end' then next_time
        end) as ts_end
from (select t.*,
             lead(time) over (partition by id order by time) as next_time,
             lead(which) over (partition by id order by time) as next_which
      from t
     ) t
where which = 'start';
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your answer for correlated subqueries, however you first subquery (select s.*,...) gives me an error in mysql: Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the outer join in this case. For example:

```
Select st.id, st.ts_start,et.ts_end from startTime st left join endTime et on st.id=et.id;
```

In this way, you will get all the records for start time irrespective of the fact whether end time available or not.

P.S: Just put the correct table name in query.

Comment: I only want to join each start with the single correct end time if it exists. A left join/outer join will give multiple end times per start time, which is not what I want

Comment: Then there should be some flag which would signify which start time belong to which end time...how are you identifying that?

Comment: @Spcoggthesecond . . . There should have been a `limit 1` in those queries.  Instead, I just added `min()`/`max()` for the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

1) Merge current and next `ts_start` into one query:

```
select
  *, 
  (select min(ts_start) from table1 as tt1 where t1.id = tt1.id and t1.ts_start < tt1.ts_star) as next_start
from table1 as t1;
```

2) Join this query with `table2`:

```
select *
from (
  select
    *, 
    (select min(ts_start) from table1 as tt1 where t1.id = tt1.id and t1.ts_start < tt1.ts_star) as next_start
  from table1 as t1) as t1 left join 
    table2 as t2 on (t1.id = t2.id and t2.ts_end between t1.ts_start and t1.next_start);
```

Should to work on most SQL-based DBMSes.

Demo with simplified data types and object names:

```
with 
  t1(x,y) as (values(123,1),(123,3),(123,5),(123,9)),
  t2(x,z) as (values(123,2),(123,7)) 
select *
from (
  select 
    *, 
    (select min(y) from t1 as tt1 where t1.x = tt1.x and t1.y < tt1.y) as next
  from t1) as t1 left join 
    t2 on (t1.x = t2.x and t2.z between t1.y and t1.next);
```